# Happens-before with different monitors

Tags: java, multithreading, happens-before

Somewhere on this site (I don't remember the question) someone claimed that happens-before relashionship holds for different monitors and for different volatile variables, i.e.

```
// Thread T1
synchronized(O1)
{
}

// Thread T2
synchronized(O2)
{
}
```

If thread T2 enters synchronized(O2){} block after thread T1 leaves synchronized(O1){} block, T2 will see all changes made by T1. The explanation was that when a thread leaves synchronized block (or writes to volatile variable) it flushes it's cache into the memory. And when a thread enters synchronized block (or reads volatile variable) it discards it's cache and reads from the memory. Is it true?

Comment: No, it isn't. It might be the case on some hardware, but it's not guaranteed by the Java Memory Model. In general, reasoning in terms of hardware implementation details (like memory and cache flushes) when dealing with multi-threaded Java code is not a good idea.

Comment: From a theoretical perspective, I think the question is a fallacy. You can't say one thread takes some action "after" another without a *happens-before* relationship, which isn't defined for separate monitors. More practically, the fact that a particular JVM might flush its cache at the end of a synchronized block doesn't mean it's guaranteed behavior.

Comment: You might be talking about my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21583879/179850

Comment: @Gray Thanks, this is indeed the question I was talking about. My bad - you actually said the opposite about happens-before relashionship.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845755/how-does-a-java-virtual-machine-implement-the-happens-before-memory-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory effects as a result of using `synchronized` or `volatile` are simply just that - memory effects. The fact that memory is observed to be "flushed from cache" has no direct relationship back to `synchronized` or `volatile`. *Happens-before* relationships are only true when operations occur as a result of actions specified in [JLS 17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5), or as a result of being in a *happens-before* chain (i.e. piggyback) with those variables. If you perform two `synchronized` or `volatile` actions on different variables, there is **NO** *happens-before* relationship.

Memory effects come as a result of *happens-before* ordering, but *happens-before* never comes as a result of memory effects.

Comment: Well put.  There is never a happens-before guarantee with different monitors but there is a memory synchronization guarantee if the order happens as the post describes.  The only correction I'd make is that one of the ways the JVM implements happens-before is through memory affects.  Memory affects don't "come as a result of happens-before ordering".

Comment: This answer is not accurate.  It's the stronger synchronizes-with relation, which the happens-before relation includes but is not restricted to, that is stronger regarding what you call memory effects: *"A synchronization order is a total order over all of the synchronization actions of an execution."*  Thus, what you call memory effects come as a result of synchronizes-with ordering, not of a happens-before relation.  For instance, there is a happens-before relation between two accesses to non-volatile variables in the same thread, but there is not a synchronizes-with relation at all.

Comment: lmao. "this answer is not accurate." "memory effects" aren't even required by the jmm to produce the desired actions even for synchronizes-with orderings. memory flushes, reads/writes to caches and main memory, and membars are hardware/implementation specific details that only used at the java level to describe analogies or provide an oversimplified explanation as to provide an example of what your hardware might do. the asker wanted to know how memory flushes works across different threads, your comment holds little relevance to the question itself and my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Happens before relationship is true for volatile variable. In case of synchronized block happens before relationship is maintained in case you are taking the lock on same object. In your case synchronized is used on different object, that means 2 different threads can enter in the two different synchronized block. In this case, java memory model doesn't guarantee happens before relationship.

Comment: The rule for volatile variables is the same. The guarantee only holds for the same variable.

Comment: But the reality of the situation is that for the JVM to support memory-barriers, it does so at the CPU cache layer, *not* at the `volatile` fieldor synchronized monitor layer.  See my answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21583879/179850

Answer (score 0):

There is not a synchronizes-with relation between different monitors.

There is a happens-before relation between acquiring a lock and the following execution and a happens-before between an execution and the following lock release.

If one thread enters a synchronized block after another thread leaves a synchronized block, there might be a happens-before relation between the execution of the synchronized block on the earlier thread and the execution of the synchronized block on the latter thread.

You can only know for sure if or when the synchronized blocks don't run concurrently with a synchronizes-with relation.  Without such relation, you have a data race.

If the code you show is all there is between the threads, then there is no synchronizes-with relation, and thus no happens-before relation.  The rest of the answer shows cases where there is more code than the one provided in the question.

One thing that establishes a synchronizes-with relation is joining a thread, such as waiting for the former thread to finish.  Another is to start a thread, such as starting the latter thread after the former finished.

```
// In a thread
t1.start();
t1.join();
t2.start();

// Or in thread 1
synchronized (O1) {
    // actions in thread 1
}
t2.start();

// Or in thread 2
t1.join();
synchronized (O2) {
    // actions in thread 2
}
```

Or if the latter thread is acquiring an outer lock owned by the former thread (that is eventually released):

```
// in thread 1
synchronized (outerLock) {
    synchronized (O1) {
        // actions in thread 1
    }
}

// in thread 2
synchronized (outerLock) {
    synchronized (O2) {
        // actions in thread 2
    }
}
```

Or if the latter thread is waiting on a lock (eventually) verifiably notified by the former thread:

```
boolean done;

// in thread 1
synchronized (O1) {
    // actions in thread 1
}
synchronized (commonLock) {
    done = true;
    commonLock.notify();
}

// in thread 2
synchronized (commonLock) {
    while (!done) {
        commonLock.wait();
    }
}
synchronized (O2) {
    // actions in thread 2
}
```

Or if the latter thread reads a volatile variable written by the former thread:

```
volatile boolean done;

// in thread 1
synchronized (O1) {
    // actions in thread 1
}
done = true;

// in thread 2
while (!done) {
    Thread.yield();
}
synchronized (O2) {
    // actions in thread 2
}
```

In this particular case, thread 2 only knows for sure it has read `done` after thread 1 has written to `done` if it observes a change.

Actually, all these cases have synchronizes-with relations, hence happens-before relations.  The synchronization actions are the ones that guarantee a total order, so not all happens-before relations are between threads.

In [Java Language Specification 8th Edition §17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html), you can read about synchronization actions:

> A synchronization order is a total order over all of the synchronization actions of an execution.

And you can read the following about happens-before relation:

> It should be noted that the presence of a *happens-before* relationship between two actions does not necessarily imply that they have to take place in that order in an implementation. If the reordering produces results consistent with a legal execution, it is not illegal.

This allows, in a single thread, non-volatile reads to be reordered as far behind as after the latest acquire and non-volatile writes to be reordered up to before the next release.

So, if you take something out of this:

- The synchronizes-with relation is about multiple threads
- Not all happens-before relations are about multiple threads

Comment: You are confusing ordering limitations around memory barriers within a certain thread's operation and happens-before operations which are between 2 different threads.  Also happens-before is less about execution order between threads which is guaranteed by the synchronized lock but about memory publication.  And I just don't understand the last paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I made the answer a bit clearer.